# Parameter values to create a vector grid with 1km x 1km cells?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, well-known-text, vector-grid

I created a shapefile from WKT in QGIS using the values from this [link](http://osm102.openstreetmap.fr/~jocelyn/polygons/get_wkt.py?id=165471&params=0.020000-0.005000-0.005000).

I want to create a vector grid with 1kmx1km cells but I can't figure out what values need to be set for the X and Y parameters. How do I calculate those?

Answer (score 6):

If you want a vector grid in kilometers:

1. Set the **project** CRS to something projected like the UTM zone of your part of the world. World mercator EPSG:3857 is **not** useful, because this projection has real meters only at the equator.
2. Load a vector or raster file of the area you are interested in, with `On-the-fly-reprojection` enabled.
3. If necessary, save the shapefile to the CRS of the project, add that to the canvas and delete the WGS84 version.
4. `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector grid` with the current extent.
   Parameter X (and Y) should be 1000 (meters).

Comment: I started a new project and set the CRS to EPSG:32615. With on the fly transformation enabled. Added the layer from the WKT provided in the question. When I tried creating the vector grid, the units were still stuck in degrees. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Saving the source shapefile to UTM solves your problem, see my extended answer. It seems to be a bug if project and layer CRS are different. I opened a ticket for it: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10059

Comment: @AndreJ, thanks for the tip about EPSG:3857. I couldn't figure out why my distance and area measurements were incorrect but after changing to the correct UTM zone the measurements are correct.